# Installing Android on VMware Workstation

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 4.4-kitkat, 7.0-nougat, vmware

I downloaded iso file of Android Kitkat, Android Marshmallow and Android Nougat from **android-x86.org/download** and followed steps from **tactig.com/install-android-nougat-vmware/** for installing all iso on VMware Workstation.

After successful installation of all these android, no android is loading successfully.

[image]
[image]

Please let me know, how to resolve it?

With Regards

FewL

Comment: You have not elaborated the problem. The first picture shows that you are booting from Bootable Drive. If you are getting that message ANDROID rootx86 something like this so wait for some time it will boot. Kindly elaborate the problem for some helpful answers. I am also working towards running it on VMware from last 5 months but problems again and again.

Comment: According to the steps explained in the link tactig.com/install-android-nougat-vmware/, The last step says, “Android-x86 is installed successfully. Reboot”.I did same and rebooted. And after reboot, first picture scenario appears. Even after 30 minutes, no changes in screen. I did shutdown the android virtual machine and ejected iso file as second picture. Then second picture scenario appeared.

Comment: @user725162 what you do is .. instead of booting from Bootable Drive...select iso file for booting then see if works